# Angular Material input validation failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, angular-material

Hello all i'm updating my forms to angular material style and i'd find something weird.

this form update the user data. so i'd load the data in a ng-model and put it in the form, so in that way the user can update its data.

the problem is the validation of one input that work in a strange way. First load with a wrong validation. all the data good, but that input doesn't validate.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <!-- LABEL DNI-->
    <label>D.N.I.</label>
    <!-- INPUT DNI-->
    <input type="text" 
           minlength="4" 
           md-maxlength="8"
           maxlength="8"
           placeholder="D.N.I."
           ng-model="user.dni" name="dni" required/>
     <!-- MENSAJES -->
      <div ng-messages="changePerfil.dni.$error"
           ng-if='changePerfil.dni.$dirty || changePerfil.dni.$touched'>
        <div ng-message="required">Este campo no puede estar vacio.</div>                            
      </div>
      <!--ICONOS DE MENSAJE -->
      <span ng-show="changePerfil.dni.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
      <span ng-show="changePerfil.dni.$dirty && changePerfil.dni.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove  form-control-feedback"></span>
</md-input-container>
```

but if this is not weird. if i delete one character and type it again, it does, the validation is done.

there's someone with a clue of what's happening?

**EDIT**

i've found the problem but is rare... it's seems to not recognize as a string that property on my `JSON`

```
var user = {
      nombre: "Paulo",
      apellido: "Galdo Sandoval",
      dni: "12345678",
      domicilio: "Street 972",
      email: "mail@hotmail.com",
      estado: "Activo",
      fechaCreacion: "2016-01-06",
      fechaModificacion: "2016-06-16"
   };
```

to make it work i must do this on my function:

```
$scope.user = datos.data;
var stringDni = datos.data.dni;
$scope.user.dni = stringDni.toString();
```

Comment: can you probably create a fiddle or some other form of working code?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in a plunker (see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beePxG)), even simulating a promise to load user data, and it's just working fine. So probably the problem is in another part of the code you didn't put in the OP. You can try to fork my plunker and reproduce the problem on it. Hope it helps

Comment: i've identified the problem, that field in particular seems to not be a string. but it is. 
the only way to validate it is use `toString()` on that string property. weird...
my `JSON` isn't wrong.